# Angular 6 - Multiple file input in single form group

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

I'm setting up an uploader for my Web Application 
which consists of 2 file input elements wherein 
the first file input will get the image and store it to the list of images variable
and the second one will get the pdf and store it to the list of pdf files variable.

the approach that I did to it is to store the file objects in the variables I named as pdfStorage and imageStorage so it will be passed to dotnet core api service after filling up the necessary fields in my form and pressing confirm button.

I don't get problem on the client side when storing the file objects to the variable. however, as soon as I send those values to the service's parameters, it always shows null for those fields.

I've viewed Request.Form in the dotnet core service and I am seeing that it's there. I don't get why it's not being populated to the ActionResult's parameter.

Here is the code that I placed in dotnet core service:

ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost("SaveNewData"),DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public ActionResult SaveNewData([FromForm]MyModelUpload modelUpload) {
    var modelUploaded = modelUpload;
    return Ok();
}
```

Model in parameter:

```
public class MyModelUpload {
    public IFormFile[] imageFile { get; set; }
    public string description {get;set;}
    public IFormFile[] pdfFileList {get;set;}
    public string uploadedBy { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dateEnd {get; set;}
}
```

And here is the test code that I used for sending the form data in angular:

```
SaveNewData(formGroupData) {
    let submitData = new FormData();
    let pdfFileArray = formGroupData.pdfStorage;

    // UPLOAD'S DETAIL
    submitData.append('title',formGroupData.title);
    submitData.append('description',formGroupData.title);
    submitData.append('uploadedBy',formGroupData.uploadedBy);
    submitData.append('dateEnd',formGroupData.dateEnd);

    // // FOR IMAGE FILE
    let imageFileObject = <File>formGroupData.imageStorage[0];
    console.log(pdfFileArray);
    submitData.append('imageFile[]',imageFileObject,imageFileObject.name);

    // // LIST OF PDF DOCS
    for(let arrayIndex in pdfFileArray) { 
        submitData
            .append(`pdfFileList[]`,pdfFileArray[arrayIndex]
                ,pdfFileArray[arrayIndex].name);
    }

    return this.http
        .post(`http://localhost:5000/Upload/SaveNewData`,submitData);
}
```

How do I send those file objects I stored on my storage variables?

Comment: Have you tried adding the Multipart/formdata header to the request? It may be helpful to also verify the network request in the Chrome debugger menu (network tab)

Comment: You can use forloop to append the Form Data

Comment: @chrisbuttacavoli I haven't done that one. I will give it a try though and give back feedback after. Thank you

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale Already did append it to FormData earlier but I still get the same result for that

Comment: Can you show the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use this:

```
 SaveNewData(formGroupData) {
    let submitData = new FormData();
    let pdfFileArray = formGroupData.pdfStorage;

    // UPLOAD'S DETAIL
    submitData.append('title',formGroupData.title);
    submitData.append('description',formGroupData.title);
    submitData.append('uploadedBy',formGroupData.uploadedBy);
    submitData.append('dateEnd',formGroupData.dateEnd);

    // // FOR IMAGE FILE
    let imageFileObject = <File>formGroupData.imageStorage[0];
    console.log(pdfFileArray);
    submitData.append('imageFile',imageFileObject);

    // // LIST OF PDF DOCS

   for (let i = 0; i < pdfFileArray.length; i++) {
     submitData.append("pdfFileList",pdfFileArray[i]);
    }

    return this.http
        .post(`http://localhost:5000/Upload/SaveNewData`,submitData);
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try too. Thank you